# Connect NosDB standalone database from powershell

Tags: powershell, nosdb, nosql

Using [powershell scripts](https://github.com/Alachisoft/NosDB/tree/master/Tool/NoSDBPSProvider) how can I connect to the standalone [NosDB](http://www.alachisoft.com/nosdb/) database?

Connect-DatabaseCluster apparently connects to the cluster by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
 get-help Connect-DatabaseCluster -full
```

You'll get a list of all the possible values. The important one for you is

```
-StandAlone [<SwitchParameter>]
Specifies if the database is standalone.

Required?                    false
Position?                    named
Default value
Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

So your command changes to

```
Connect-DatabaseCluster -StandAlone
```

Its written in the documentation